# Fragment doesn't show up

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, xamarin

I'm trying to use Fragments in Xamarin.Android and it doesn't show up. I can't figure out why it happens. I also have to pass data to the Fragment.

Here is a simplified version of my root Activity :

```
using SupportToolbar = Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar;
using SupportFragment = Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment;

public class MenuFollowedBalloonActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.menuFollowedBalloon);

        var ft = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        Bundle args2 = new Bundle (); 
        args2.PutString ("listBalloons", jsonCatchedBalloons);
        args2.PutInt ("typeBalloons", 0);
        _catchedBalloonsFragment.Arguments = args2;
        ft.Add(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, _catchedBalloonsFragment, "catchedBalloonsFragment");
        ft.Show(_catchedBalloonsFragment);
        ft.DisallowAddToBackStack();
        ft.Commit(); 
    }
}
```

Here is my Fragment :

```
public class ListBalloonFragment : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
{
    private List<Balloon> _balloonsList;
    private ScrollView _scrollView;
    private LinearLayout _layout;
    private int _type;

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.listBalloonFragment, container, false);

        Console.WriteLine(this.Activity.Class.Name);
        return view;
    }

    public override void OnResume ()
    {
        base.OnResume ();
        _scrollView = this.View.FindViewById<ScrollView>(Resource.Id.titleBalloonList);
        _layout = this.View.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.listLayout);
        string jsonBalloons = Arguments.GetString("listBalloons");
        _balloonsList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Balloon>>(jsonBalloons);
        _type = Arguments.GetInt("typeBalloons");
        Console.WriteLine (_type);
        if (_balloonsList.Count == 0)
        {
            TextView noBalloons;

            noBalloons = new TextView(this.Activity);
            noBalloons.Text = "Vous n'avez aucun ballons suivis ni de ballons à renvoyer";
            _layout.AddView(noBalloons);
        }
        else
        {
            AddTextViewFromBalloons(_balloonsList, _type);
        }
    }
}
```

The main.axml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroundInternPagesLayerList"
    android:weightSum="100">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/menuFollowedBalloonsTabs"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#FEFEFE"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="92" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And the fragment :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000">
    <ScrollView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/titleBalloonList">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/listLayout"/> 
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The fragment is well-created and the data is passed with no problems but the fragment doesn't show up. I have the latest Android SDK and Xamarin version. I have the support v4 and v7 up to date.

How can i make it visible ?

Comment: try with this(replace ft.Add and below):
ft.Replace (Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, _catchedBalloonsFragment);
ft.AddToBackStack (null);
ft.Commit ();

Comment: I was calling a second time setContentView in OnResume. My mistake ^^

Comment: Always Debug first when you have a problem, you could have seen this instantly :)

Comment: You mean step by step debugging ?

Comment: Yes or you can start from the last procedure / function and set some breakpoints if you dont want to debug the whole code